# Show custom html code in react-chartjs-2 legend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to create this custom chart using react-chartjs-2:

[image: chart model]

I need to create those custom labels with onClick function but I can't find the correct way to do it, I used plugins and callbacks, but nothing seems to work.

Here is part of my options code:

```
const options = {
responsive: true,
scales: {
  x: {
    grid: {
      drawOnChartArea: false,
    },
  },
  y: {
    grid: {
      drawBorder: false,
      drawOnChartArea: false,
      color: 'white',
    },
    ticks: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
},
plugins: {
  legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
      render: 'value',
      fontColor: '#fff',
      precision: 0,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontStyle: 'bold',
      position: 'outside',
      outsidePadding: 4,
      textMargin: 4,
      overlap: true,
      showZero: true,
      callbacks: function (value) {
        return '<span style="color: red">' + value + '</span>';
      },
      usePointStyle: true,
      font: {
        size: 20,
        color: '#151B27',
      },
    },
  },

  title: {
    display: true,
    align: 'start',
    text: 'text',
    color: '#525F77',
    font: {
      size: 16,
      family: 'Inter',
      weight: 'normal',
      style: 'normal',
    },
  },
},
```

};

I'm using react and javascript.
Do you know what's going on?

Comment: I think you need a HTML legend plugin for that: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/html.html

Comment: I added that code but didn't work either. I don't know if I need to change something to use it with react charts.

Answer (score 1):

As @user2057925 said, I need to follow [this tutorial](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/html.html), but I have to adapt it to `react-chartjs-2` like this:

```
<Bar
    options={options}
    data={dataChart}
    plugins={[htmlLegendPlugin]}
    redraw={true}
/>
<div id='label-container'></div>
```

As you can see, you don't have to add plugins section to options object, but you have to pass it like a prop to Bar chart.
Also you can see a div with an ID, there will contain your custom labels (don't forget to hide the draw ones)

The plugin's definition is like this:

```
const htmlLegendPlugin = {
    id: 'htmlLegend',
    afterUpdate(chart, args, options) {
        items.forEach((item, index) => {
            // Build your html for label
        })
    }
}
```